# How to figure out SNR of a transducer

Tags: transducer

This is a novice question.

There is an accelerometer which outputs -10 to +10V voltage output.
If I sample the output for constant output(accelerometer is not moving), can I say anything about signal to noise ratio by looking at samples? What should be the method to investigate SNR here or impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I sample the output for constant output(accelerometer is not
>   moving), can I say anything about signal to noise ratio by looking at
>   samples?

You can only say what the noise is. Here's how you compute the noise RMS level based on taking many samples: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/applications/methods-to-obtain-trusted-rms-results-on-the-r-s-rtm-application-card_56279-138306.html).

Subtract your static DC offset from the noise samples before squaring each term. Alternatively, if your noise is gaussian in nature you can estimate the RMS value from the peak values: -

[image]

A reasonable approximation would divide the p-p value by 6.6 to get RMS. Picture directly above taken from [here](https://www.edn.com/Home/PrintView?contentItemId=4422645). Here's a picture from TI that shows the reverse calculation: -

[image]

Regarding your signal, if you know what performance your transducer gives i.e. its transfer function then you can assume that a signal is present in the noise you have measured and calculate SNR.

Comment: They provide only one page data sheet: https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf I need to say something about the noise but I dont know where to start with. I can sample and log the data but I dont know what should I do rest to say anything about the noise. I was thinking to make the accelormeter stay in rest with constant voltage output with some noise on it, but how to quantify noise superimposed on the DC here? I dont know. Would rms of the signal reveal something? I really dont know where to start with.

Comment: SNR in voltage terms is the RMS ratios of signal and noise so RMS is the right way.

Comment: Is what you measure corresponding with what the DS says: Output Noise <2.5 μV RMS From 0 To 50 Hz? Bear in mind that the p-p noise is theoretically infinite but a lot of people say that multiplying RMS by 6.6 gives the p-p noise to a probability of 1 in 1000.

Comment: But lets say signal is f and noise is n. In my sampled logged data i will be seeing (f+n) only. since i dont know what is f or what if n and I only know their sum, how can I find (f_rms/n_rms)? That is my dilemma.

Comment: If you know the toal signal (X) and noise (N) then S = \$\sqrt{X^2 - N^2}\$

Comment: Im sorry maybe idiotic question but how can I find N? I only have the sum of the expected DC signal and the noise.

Comment: The DC offset is null and void so noise is how much the DC offset moves. Square each sample (after subtracting the DC offset), average those squared samples over a period of time and then take the square root - that is what root-mean-squared means. Or calculate the p-p and divide by 6.6 to get a reasonable approximation. Do both and see what figures you get.

Comment: Oh so lets say I have the sampled logged data V. First I will remove the average of V from V (means removing all DC component). Then I will have (V-Vaverage), and the rms of this will give me the rms of the noise right i.e N in your equation? Is that correct understood you?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Woow great. One last question, so if I find it more than 2.5uV (which their specs says), I should conclude it is my wiring or external noise is causing this extra noise?

Comment: Either would contribute plus not having a decoupling capacitor across the power terminals (in some cases). You should also do a null noise test with your measurement system's inputs connected to a low noise source too. Just to rule out self-induced noise.

Comment: After following your replies, I now plan to check the measurement system's own noise (i.e data-acq device's own noise). You mentioned low noise source for the inputs. As a low noise source, should I use a for example 9V battery or just short the inputs and quantify the noise of the measurement system?

Comment: @Andy 6.6 RMS = 6.6 sigma, or approx. 1 part per million

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the old memory cells aint what they used to be!

Comment: @panicattack you should probably short the inputs to 0 volts (mid range of accelerometer).

Answer (score 1):

It's typical in data sheet specs to list SNR as the ratio of full-scale signal to noise floor. If your accelerometer is actually isolated from all forms of acceleration including seismic noise and tilting, measuring the RMS voltage will give you the noise floor. This is non-trivial with a good (eg. tactical grade) accelerometer.

Data sheets will probably assume a DC signal so the RMS full scale is 10V.

If you want to know what the real SNR is in a particular application, of course you have to know the signal.

Comment: Hello you wrote "If your accelerometer is actually isolated from all forms of acceleration including seismic noise and tilting, measuring the RMS voltage will give you the noise floor." RMS voltage or standard deviation?